# Drools for ECA/Reaction Rules having AND, SEQ, OR in Condition

Tags: rules, drools, rule-engine, complex-event-processing

It seems, Drools is quite prominent around here, so I thought I'd ask:

Can Drools rules be used for event pattern detection?
Patterns are of the from: `"Event_x" SEQ/AND/OR "Event_z"`. The example below indicates the desired usage. The Events are identified using a previously known ID.

```
rule "Rule x"
when 
      Event1 SEQ/AND/OR Event2
then
    System.out.println("Event1 SEQ/AND/OR Event2");
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. "and" and "or" are used directly as conditional elements:

```
rule X when
    Event1() and Event2()
...

rule Y when
    Event3() or Event4()
```

They can obviously be combined, nested, etc... check Drools documentation for details.

Up to Drools 5.4, sequencies are defined using temporal operators like "before","after", etc. For instance:

```
rule Z when
    $e1 : Event1() and $e2 : Event2( this after $e1 )
...
```

For Drools 5.5, the several flavors of sequence conditional elements are planned:

```
rule W when
    Event1() -> Event2()
...
```

Where -> is the followed by operator, => is strictly followed by, etc.

Details:

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/EventSequencing#4_Definition_Sequence_Conditional_Elements

Comment: Just stumbled upon this on and sounds like a great addition to Drools Fusion. Is there any schedule when Drools 5.5 will be released?

Comment: Plan is for the end of the year.